Unable to edit on multiple tables opened simultaneously on DBeaver, says couldn't find table metadata
When I select and launch multiple Select SQL queries on DBeaver, which open several tables simultaneously, I can no longer edit data on those table because DBeaver seems no longer able to find the tables metadata; and therefore, said tables are locked in read-only mode, preventing me from editing data.
Dbeaver read-only mode issue
How can I make DBeaver allow me to edit in this case again?
I selected multiples select SQL queries with the mouse, clicked on the button Execute, displaying all the tables with the requested results, and tried to edit the cells.
DBeaver should have let me edit those cells.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
